# UIWebView cut off at the bottom by UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a `UITabBarController` at the bottom of my application and for one view I would like to display many component and I have a `UIWebView` and at the bottom I have my `UITabBarController`. My issue is that my `UIWebView` is cut off at the bottom by my `UITabBarController` because in my .xib my `UIWebView` take all the remaining space.

How can I solve that programmatically that my WebView knows when she must stop to display (just before the top of my `UITabBarController`) ? I would like a solution for IOS6/7 please.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set bottom edge inset to your webView.scrollView.

Like:

```
self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, *tabbar_height*, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! The tabBar height it's a value fix for all the  IOS version and all the devices ?

Comment: Just set bottom inset with self.tabbarController.tabBar.bounds.size.height. It will guarantee correct inset on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that Kirvoblotsky suggested will work for iOS 7.0 but not on iOS 7.1. On iOS7.1 your web view will have an additional inset on top of bottom tab bar.

In the view controller that contains your web view you need to add this modification:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    ...
    // put this IF statemenet in the end
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
    }
}
```

If you don't do it like this then you need to do if statement when setting contentInset:

```
if (*iOS version == 7.1*) {
    self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.f, 0.0f);
} else if (*iOS version == 7.0) {
    self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, *tabbar_height*, 0.0f);
}
```